# Enrollment information

Tags: desire2learn, valence

I'm looking for the most effective way to extract the following information from D2L.

For a given user find all Department in which he is **not** enrolled, but **is** enrolled in **any** Offerings belonging to this Department.

The only solution I see is:

1. Call *GET .../enrollments/users/{id}/orgUnits* with type = Offering into List1
2. For each entry in List1 call *GET .../courses/{courseId}* to get course department information and build on-the-fly List2 of unique departments.
3. Call *GET .../enrollments/users/{id}/orgUnits* with type = Department into List3
4. Compare List2 vs List3

It's obvious that if user is teaching many Courses then too many calls will be required in step2.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your step *2* which starts with the set of the student's enrolled course offerings, you may find it easier to call [GET /d2l/api/lp/(version)/orgstructure/(orgUnitId)/ancestors/](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/orgunit.html#get--d2l-api-lp-(version)-orgstructure-(orgUnitId)-ancestors-) to find all the departments containing those course offerings, and produce your *List 2*.

Unfortunately, the Valence Learning Framework doesn't really give you any set-predicate API calls around the org structure (to determine if a given orgUnit *Y* is a descendant of another orgUnit *X*, and so forth).

Comment: Thanks, Viktor. Fortunately for me my Course can belong to only 1 department, but this call you recommended might be useful in future.

Comment: Please confirm again that there is no better way than 1 by 1 calls in step2.

Comment: Very, very few of the Valence Learning Framework API calls allow you to say "please _do this thing_ for _all_ the org unit ID contexts I'm passing you in a list". Nearly all the API calls are specifically designed to operate within the context of a single user's actions within a single org unit context, or operate upon a single org unit. So, yes, once you have a list of org unit IDs, you have to iterate over those org units to find the list of ancestors for each one.

Comment: Thanks again. No I didn't have a list in mind - just additional parameter **DepartmentId** on .../enrollments/users/{id}/orgUnits